# How to remove and sort dynamically created RenderFragments in Blazor

Tags: javascript, sorting, blazor, render

I am not able to correctly delete or sort dynamically created component in Blazor.

I create my objects as follows in my page body:

```
private RenderFragment CreateComponentObject() => builder =>
    {
        foreach (var item in myObjects)
        {
             builder.OpenComponent(i, typeof(MyBlazorComponent));
                    builder.AddAttribute(1, "ComponentID", item.ID);
                    builder.AddAttribute(1, "ComponentName", item.Name);
                    builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(i, inst => { ReferenceObjects.Add((MyBlazorComponent)inst); });
                    builder.CloseComponent();

        }
        i++;
};
```

Now I will need to both be able to

```
1. Sort the components by ID or Name
2. Eventually remove one or more components
```

I tried to sort the items through a simple sort script, but it does not work. Alternatively, I 've tried to "remove" all the components through builder.Clean and to re-enter in the CreateComponentObject function, ordering the components to be created in the desired way.
But this strategy does not work well, since the order changes for some parameters and for others it doesn't.

Example: if I clear the builder and re-allocate components by name, I will see the ID of the component following the right order, but the name will not change

```
Before:
ID 19 Name Kiki
ID 20  Name Jiji

After:
ID 20 Name Kiki
ID 19 Name Jiji
```

Does anyone have an idea how to face my two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbering should [follow linenumbers, not for loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sequence-numbers-relate-to-code-line-numbers-and-not-execution-order).

```
 builder.OpenComponent(1, typeof(MyBlazorComponent));
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "ComponentID", item.ID);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ComponentName", item.Name);
        builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(4, inst => { ReferenceObjects.Add((MyBlazorComponent)inst); });
        builder.SetKey(item);     // makes the sequence nrs less relevant
        builder.CloseComponent();

// i++;
```

But you probably want to use  SetKey to override the numbering.

Comment: To add to that, I'd recommend you consider using a loop and/or a ChildContent so that you can declare the components you need rather than manage the render tree yourself. If you have many many components that you may need to render, consider cascading that through a child component that determines what to render based on your logic (a series of if-blocks or swtich-es). It might be easier to maintain in the longer run

Comment: Thank you both very much! By adding the SetKey my code works, and I will try to declare my component through ChildContent as rdmptn suggests.